# Conway's Game of Life in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conways-game-of-life

I'm doing the Game of Life by John Conway and I have been trying for such a long time to do this but it keeps giving me this error:

```
if matrix[i+1][j] == 1:
```

`IndexError: list index out of range`

I don't know what's wrong with it, normally `m[i+1][j]` works for finding the specific position I'm asking for.

Comment: you will need to show the code where the error is, and what is the `matrix` refers to.

Comment: You get the error, because either the number of rows in your matrix is less than or equal to `i` or the number of columns is less than or equal to `j-1`.

Comment: I tried putting a validation for that before the statment like this: while i < len(matrix) and j<len(matrix)

Comment: Could you post the actual code? There isn't enough context to know why `matrix[i+1][j] == 1` would be outside the list range.

Comment: i may be less than the length but i +1 is not. You would need i to be less than the length of the matrix -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the other answers, I will assume that your question is about why you get this error in your GoL implementation and is not a question about what the error means.

You do not provide a lot of information about when the error occurs, but a common issue in implementing GoL is how to handle the boundaries.  This is discussed in [Wikipedia's GoL article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).  Most likely you get your error when you are trying to compute a neighborhood at the boundary.  Here is one common solution. Extend your grid by one on each side (including top and bottom). Call the new cells "boundary cells"; use them to store the state of the "neighors" that would be there with a toroidal topology.  Compute the next state only for the non-boundary cells; when you update their state, also update each boundary cell to the toroidally "wrapped" cell it represents.

Answer (score -1):

You are adding `1` to `i` ts for the last `i` so you are  most likely falling off the end of your list:

```
In [3]: l = [1,2]   
In [4]: l[0]
Out[4]: 1    
In [5]: l[1]
Out[5]: 2    
In [6]: l[1+1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f4912ad93661> in <module>()
----> 1 l[1+1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```